# How to install g++ 4.8?

Tags: software-installation, g++

I have G++ 4.7.2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to install 4.8.

I downloaded the file from the GNU repository.

After `configure` and `make`, I get the following error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [build/gengtype] Error 1..
```

etc.

Is there ANY way to install 4.8 on Ubuntu?

Comment: these details will not be enough .  we need more log .

Comment: You say "etc.", please elaborate and paste the full error message here.

Comment: Uhm, 4.8.0 hasn't been released yet (at the time of writing). It's still in development... [GNU GCC releases page](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html). So please elaborate more on where you got this copy and why you need a development version (you probably don't).

Comment: Why is this duplicate of [How to install gcc-4.8 in Ubuntu 12.04 from the terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal)? g++ and gcc are different packages!

Comment: @RaduRădeanu you are probably right in view of the fact that the ppa shown there does not provide g++-4.8, but it also describes how to build the package from source.

Comment: @guntbert Maybe you have right (where are g++ 4.8 sources?!?), but one can get confused about this. If one search on Google "how to install g++ 4.8" and if he find that this is duplicate of "[How to install gcc-4.8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal)" he can thing that these packages are one and the same.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment `g++-4.8` doesn't exist in Ubuntu repositories since is still in unstable or testing version and also there is no any PPA from where you can get `g++-4.8` (even if you can find in other places that can be found in https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test - check the link and you will see that is not there). But it can be found in [Debian repositories](http://packages.debian.org/sid/g++-4.8). Depending on your system architecture, download:

- [g++-4.8_4.8.1-10_amd64.deb](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/g++-4.8_4.8.1-10_amd64.deb) for Ubuntu 64-bit
- [g++-4.8_4.8.1-10_i386.deb](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/g++-4.8_4.8.1-10_i386.deb) for Ubuntu 32-bit.

More about: http://packages.debian.org/sid/g++-4.8, http://packages.debian.org/jessie/g++-4.8 (you should check also the dependencies).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what we do with the downloaded file? Thanks

Comment: @mezamorphic You have to install it. Just double click on it.