# How to install gcc-4.8

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I checked the gcc version on my system.

It is currently at 4.6.3.
I read that gcc-4.8 is out.

I tried the following commands without success:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc (gcc is already the newest version)
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 (unable to locate package)
```

Does anyone know how to install this package on 12.04?

Comment: @maggotbrain's answer worked for me, though I had to add: sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib as I was running into this issue:
http://superuser.com/questions/432202/make-fails-compiling-gcc

Comment: Note to future googlers:
If you get error message like undefined reference to `lexer_line' It is because of missing tools: bison and flex sudo apt-get install bison sudo apt-get install flex as pointed out here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262531/trouble-building-gcc-4-6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262531/trouble-building-gcc-4-6)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

**Is GCC-4.8 available for 12.04 Precise now?**

**Update**: As of 6/05/2013, there is currently a release of gcc 4.8.1 for 12.04(precise) available at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test.

The short answer is: *`gcc-4.8` is currently available for 12.04(Precise) via the toolchain PPA* **or** by compiling the source(see below for details).

**Release Announcement**

The [announcement for the release of gcc-4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-announce/2013/msg00001.html) was made on March 22nd, so you probably won't be seeing this in an official repository just yet.

However, it appears that Launchpad does have a PPA available for the [toolchain](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain) test builds that does include gcc-4.8, here: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test

According to the [changelog and package list](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test/+packages), there are debs for i386, amd64, arm, and powerpc and were built against raring 13.04.

The latest available version of gcc, for 12.04, is 4.8.1 and is available in the toolchain PPA.

**Adding the toolchain/test PPA:**

To add the PPA to your system, open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50
```

You will also be prompted to install a number of suggested packages.
These packages are recommended, but optional, for the installation of gcc-4.8.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

**What C++ features are available in gcc-4.8 that are not available in gcc-4.7.2?**

- According to [GNU.ORG](http://gnu.org), gcc-4.7, supports a number of [C++11 features](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html).
- As of the gcc-4.8 release, gcc-4.7 does not support 8 out of 64 features  (See [C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html))
- These features are:

  ```
  Language Features
  - Rvalue references for *this
  - Generalized attributes
  - Alignment support
  - Inheriting constructors
  Concurreny
  - Bidirectional Fences
  - Memory model
  - Abandoning a process and at_quick_exit
  - Thread-local storage
  ```
- For a full list of changes in gcc-4.8, see the [Changelist](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html)

**I need these gcc features on 12.04 Precise, now. How can I get them?**

**Building GCC-4.8 from source:**

If you need gcc-4.8 on 12.04 now, your only option is to [build it from source](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/).

Please read the [GCC installation FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) prior to installation.

You can download gcc-4.8 from one of gnu.org's [mirror sites](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) or directly from their [SVN server](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html).

Here is an example of steps to compile from source (see [here](http://dollarvar.blogspot.com/2013/03/building-gcc-48.html) for additional details.) Note that these may vary depending on your system and preferences.

1. Download the [source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html)

   - Make a build directory ( `mkdir gcc-build && cd gcc-build`)
   - Download the source file: `wget http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.0/gcc-4.8.0.tar.bz2` (adjust this command to use an appropriate [mirror site](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html).
   - Unzip the file (`tar -xvjf <file name>`)
2. Install some additional libraries (`sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev libc6-dev`)
3. Compile the source: `./gcc-4.8.0/configure --prefix=/app/gcc/4.8.0`
4. Run `make` (This will take some time to complete. Go make some coffee, or bake some cookies. ;-))
5. Install the code: `sudo make install`

Once this process has completed, run the command `gcc --version` to verify that the installation has completed successfully. You should see something similar to the following output:

```
maggotbrain@foucault:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Linaro 4.8.0) 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The bottom line: Thank all those folks who provide easy to install Ubuntu backports for you. Give them some of the cookies that you baked while running `make`. ;-)

Comment: Excellent answer, except: `E: Unable to locate package gcc-4.8`

Comment: Installing the additional libraries was not enough for me, but running `./contrib/download_prerequisites.sh` fixed it (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253695/building-gcc-requires-gmp-4-2-mpfr-2-3-1-and-mpc-0-8-0).

Comment: Note: I also had to install the package g++-4.8 (in addition to gcc-4.8) to be able to compile C++ code. Otherwise I was getting the compile error: `gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory 4.8`.

Comment: I was able to successfully install gcc4.8 on Precise

Comment: Doesn't work for me on amd64, libgcc1=1:4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04:i386 doesn't exist.

Comment: @pts I would recommend submitting a new question referencing this specific question as I haven't looked into any 32 vs 64 bit issues. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Where should I run `make`?

Comment: For those who faced @Boris problem (like me) here is how to install g++ http://askubuntu.com/questions/175571/why-cant-i-install-g

Comment: @ John Dibling - Sure enough the exposed method does install the files, however as such you never build any package nor install any ... hence you can't find it (them) :-). Well there is a quick way to build automatically the packages using  the debian folder from [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8). I've done it successfuly for other packages. This solution will install All the related packages including g++ etc...

Comment: KHODA PEDAR MADARETO BIAMORZE, Thanks man, very helpful

Comment: I followed PPA method and this is one of my Terminal output during installation: "Note, selecting 'gcc-3.4-hppa64' for regex 'gcc-3.4'". I don't see "gcc-3.4" under "/usr/bin" nor run `$ gcc-3.4`. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

So answer above works, at least for manual install. Though even after `sudo make install`, running `gcc` still just runs the stock version 4.6.3. Even trying `gcc-4.8` or `gcc-4.8.0` doesn't work. Running `/app/gcc/4.8.0/bin/gcc` appears to be the only thing that works for me. I mean it is kind of lame but at least it works.

Comment: [:facepalm:] Before you call things "lame" perhaps you should upgrade your operating systems knowledge. You could start with reading up on the concept of PATH: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Comment: Sure thing as well, as you do not install any package with DEBIAN/postinst script you have to set manually the default version to use by your system through the [update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) cmd. line ... If you used --prefix=/usr there is no need to meddle with PATH ...