# Can't install gcc 4.8, dependency issues

Tags: upgrade, gcc

I tried downoading 4.8 for 12.04 from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test/+packages (I did not find for 13.04 as is mentioned here: [How to install gcc-4.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal)) and I think I messed up trying to install it.

`apt-get install gcc-4.8` gives :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

followed by a long list of packages and the recommendation:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

but `apt-get -f install` says

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Please help I need it for the C++11 support

Update 04/28/2013

This was fixed with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
apt-get upgrade -f
```

Many thanks to everyone for trying to help!

Comment: You can add this as an answer to show that it is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to install gcc with C++11 support is to do

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then compile the source code with

```
g++ <Filename>.cpp -std=c++0x
```

Comment: but you still need to add ppa otherwise it will install 4.7

Comment: Even with 4.7 we can compile C++11.

Comment: ty for updating ....i dont know anything about C++11

Comment: thanks for answering!, what I did is download the *i386.deb files and run sudo dpkg -i *.deb, which finished with various errors and now I get 70 broken packages in the Synaptic Package Manager. When I tried apt-get install build essential (I do have the ppa) I got :E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: 4.7 does not support inhereted constructors aka using A:A etc

Answer (score 1):

You can install **gcc 4.8 in Ubuntu 13.04**, just follow the commands

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base
```

Source [How to install gcc-4.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal)

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering! Please read my comment to the above answer I am getting the same errors when I try apt-get update, mea culpa! Package Manager was open now I get: sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-4.8-base is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
<list of packages follows> and finally E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: ... as with apt-get install build-essential above

Answer (score 1):

install two debian packages...(you can search Google to download and install it)

64-bit

libisl10_0.11.1-2_amd64.deb

libcloog-isl4_0.18.0-2_amd64.deb

command: sudo dpkg -i 'package_name'

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install g++-4.8 gcc-4.8

Comment: thanks for answering! please read my comments to the above answers