# Why does apt-get want to remove gcc-4.8 and g++-4.8 when I try to upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, gcc

I am trying to upgrade **gcc-4.8.1** and **g++-4.8.1** to **4.8.2**. I added the PPA containing g++-4.8.2, ran `apt-get update` and then when I try:

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for martin: 
...
The following packages have been kept back:
  cpp-4.8 g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgcc1 libgcc1-dbg libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0
  libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

the packages I need to upgrade are kept back. When I try:

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  g++-4.8 gcc-4.8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev libgcc1 libgcc1-dbg
  libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6
  libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
14 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 32.4 MB disk space will be freed.
```

the system wants to **remove g++-4.8 gcc-4.8**.

When I try to install **gcc-4.8 from Synaptic** It wants to **remove g++-4.8** and when I tell that it is ok to remove it, I get this error:

[image]

How can I install **gcc-4.8.2** and **g++-4.8.2**?

**EDIT:**

As [souravc suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/424932/64420), I did

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}'
```

and this is the result:

```
autoconf
bcmwl-kernel-source
dkms
lib64gcc1
libbotan-1.10-0
libc6-amd64
libc6-x32
libpcrecpp0:i386
libqt5clucene5:i386
libqt5declarative5:i386
libqt5designer5:i386
libqt5designercomponents5:i386
libqt5help5:i386
libqt5quickparticles5:i386
libqt5quicktest5:i386
libqt5script5:i386
libsigsegv2:i386
libx32gcc1
libx32stdc++6
linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic
usb-creator-gtk
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install gcc 4.8, dependency issues](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286379/cant-install-gcc-4-8-dependency-issues)

Comment: @adityapatil It is not a duplicate. I read that question and did not solve my problem. If you see the solution in one of the answers, could you please post it as the answer to this question?

Comment: Have you tried all solutions? or at least those who are upvoted? Also read [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/184942).

Comment: @adityapatil Those are not solutions to the problem I am solving.

Comment: try installing thrugh terminal using the options `-fm`.

Comment: @adityapatil Thank you, but the result is the same. The system wants to remove g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 in exchange for upgrading the 14 packages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13205/discussion-between-aditya-patil-and-martin-drozdik)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc 4.8.2 is currently under development and will only be released for trusty(14.04LTS).

The current latest version available for Ubuntu 13.10 saucy is 4.8.1 and it will not be updated to 4.8.2

Comment: For anyone needing explanation, read [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13205/discussion-between-aditya-patil-and-martin-drozdik).

Comment: Could you summarize the discussion instead and add it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this message as you have broken packages in your system. To be sure try this in your terminal,

```
dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}'
```

You should get a list showing above packages.

Run the following in a terminal to get rid of this,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

To install `gcc-4.8` and `g++-4.8`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same results. Moreover the list of packages I get (see my edit) is not the same as the ones I am trying to upgrade.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik there was a typo. sorry for that. did you run those `autoremove` and `autoclean` commands? are you still getting the notice when going to `apt-get update`?

Comment: Yes, I typed the commands without the typo and it still doesn't work

Comment: @souravc come here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13205/discussion-between-aditya-patil-and-martin-drozdik