# cmath: No such file or directory #include <cmath>

Tags: gcc

I downloaded and try to installed the package "wfconvert" from [this link](http://qmcpack.cmscc.org/tutorials/bulk-solid) . but I got some error.

here what I did:

1. copy the wfconvert folder in root "/"
2. `cd /wfconvert/build/`

   ```
   root@geant4:/wfconvert/build# cmake ..

   -- Current revision : 65 modified on 2013-01-16 22:14:53 +0330 (Wed, 16 Jan 2013)  
   -- Found mpi.h and libraries. Check for working mpi compiler  
   -- MPI is disabled  
   -- Failed to link LAPACK, BLAS, ATLAS libraries with environments. Going to search standard paths.  
   -- LAPACK_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/liblapack.so  
   -- BLAS_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libblas.so  
   -- CXX compiler flags:  -g -O3 -ftemplate-depth-60 -Drestrict=__restrict__ -funroll-all-loops   -finline-limit=1000 -Wno-deprecated  -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fopenmp  
   -- CC  compiler flags:  -O3 -Drestrict=__restrict__ -funroll-all-loops   -finline-limit=1000 -std=gnu99 -fomit-frame-pointer  -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3  
   -- LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/libxml2  
   -- LIBXML2_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libxml2.so  
   -- HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include  
   -- HDF5_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libhdf5.so  
   -- FFTW_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include  
   -- FFTW_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libfftw3.so  
   -- Ready to build qmcpack  
   -- Configuring done  
   -- Generating done  
   -- Build files have been written to: /wfconvert/build
   ```
3. make command

   ```
   root@geant4:/wfconvert/build# make

   [  1%] Building C object src/einspline/CMakeFiles/einspline.dir/bspline_create.c.o  
   In file included from /wfconvert/src/einspline/bspline_base.h:24:0,  
            from /wfconvert/src/einspline/bspline_create.h:24,  
            from /wfconvert/src/einspline/bspline_create.c:21:  
   /wfconvert/build/src/Common/config.h:65:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory  
    #include <cmath> 
            ^
   compilation terminated.    
   make[2]: *** [src/einspline/CMakeFiles/einspline.dir/bspline_create.c.o] Error 1  
   make[1]: *** [src/einspline/CMakeFiles/einspline.dir/all] Error 2  
   make: *** [all] Error 2
   ```

**I don`t know what to do!

here is my cmath file list:**

```
root@geant4:/# find -name cmath
./opt/root5.32.00/cint/cint/include/cmath
./app/gcc/4.8.0/include/c++/4.8.0/ext/cmath
./app/gcc/4.8.0/include/c++/4.8.0/cmath
./app/gcc/4.8.0/include/c++/4.8.0/tr1/cmath
./usr/include/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath
./usr/include/boost/tr1/tr1/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.5/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1_impl/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/cmath
./usr/share/gccxml-0.9/GCC/2.95/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/stage1-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/stage1-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/stage1-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/c/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/c_global/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/c_std/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/26_numerics/headers/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/tr1/8_c_compatibility/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/prev-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/prev-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/prev-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
```

and

```
root@geant4:/# uname -a
Linux geant4 3.0.0-32-generic-pae #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 21 16:09:48 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Please help me.

Comment: Cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/q/17147170/3701431

Comment: I’m voting to close: According to the related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17147170/3701431), it looks like a bug in the downloaded source ([wrong file extension of the source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147170/cmath-no-such-file-or-directory-when-compiled-with-gcc#comment24848329_17147483)). Moreover, the link to the source is dead as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect corrupt installation of development tools or something like that. First thing I would do is re install build package

```
sudo apt-get purge build-essential
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If the problem still persists post it back

**Just curious:** How did you install GCC 4.8? I have 13.04 and it have 4.7.3
So that might be an issue if was not done properly!

Comment: I did your instruction but the problem did not solve. for installing gcc-4.8 refer to the link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal

Comment: Can you upload CmakeList.txt or screenshot of CMake GUI configurations? What happens if you cahnge line from <cmath> to <cmath.h>?

Comment: download the [CmakeList.txt](http://s4.picofile.com/file/7810019672/CMakeLists.txt.html) , and when I replace the `<cmath>` with `<cmath.h>` the error remain the same.

Comment: To convert C++ sources to C (or ancient C++), `<cmath>` should be replaced with `<math.h>` (no `c` which denotes C standard libraries used in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Is libm automatically linked too, while compiling ?

libm is for compiler g++ and is automatically linked. If you use gcc as compiler you need to link manually with math.h

I found this link here about different compilers generally :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c

By the way - there is http://boost.org

You could compile and include with boost-libraries too.

Comment: how can I linked manually to math.h

Comment: with gcc it looks this: gcc example.c -o example -lm   for more precise compiling you do this: gcc -ggdb -Wall example.c -o example -lm

Comment: with gcc it looks this: gcc example.c -o example -lm   for more precise compiling you do this: gcc -ggdb -Wall example.c -o example -lm (provided - there is: #include <math.h> at the beginning of example.c)

Answer (score 0):

With gcc it looks this:

```
gcc example.c -o example -lm
```

for more precise compiling (with debugging output in case of failures) you do this:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall example.c -o example -lm
```

lm is here the linking with the math-library of gcc (there is #include math.h at the beginning of example.c).