# How to install gcc-4.8 (x64) on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, gcc

I want to install the newer 4.8 version of gcc, and when I searched for a solution i found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/271561/59634). But when trying to use the solution I ran into a quite annoying problem:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
>
> sudo apt-get update

work like a charm (or at least they don't complain)

> sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8

results in (sorry for the german, but maybe the format of the message triggers some memories, therefore I did not just post my translation):

> Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten,
>   dass Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie
>   die Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete
>   noch nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
>   Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu
>   lösen:
>
> Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
>
> ```
> gcc-4.8:i386 : Hängt ab von: cpp-4.8:i386 (= 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.10.3) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: binutils:i386 (>= 2.22) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>
>             Hängt ab von: libgcc-4.8-dev:i386 (= 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.10.3) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: libcloog-isl4:i386 (>= 0.17) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: libgmp10:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: libisl10:i386 (>= 0.10) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: libmpc2:i386 soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: libmpfr4:i386 (>= 3.1.0) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Hängt ab von: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) soll aber nicht installiert werden
>             Empfiehlt: libc6-dev:i386 (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) soll aber nicht installiert werden
> ```
>
> E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.

Which is basically saying (giving: a rough translation):

> There are some packages which cannot be installed. Meaing, that there
>   is a situation where you are using a unstable distribution therefore
>   some packages are not made or did not leave incoming yet. The
>   following information may help you to find a solution
>
> The following pacakges have unresolved dependencies:
>
> ```
> gcc-4.8:i386 : depends on: cpp-4.8:i386 (= 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.10.3) shall/may not be installed 
>  ...and so on, as the text is the same i hope i do not have to copy paste it
> ```
>
> E: Occuring Problem could not be managed, you got reserved damaged packets.

Further information on my System:

> uname -a
>
> Linux name 3.5.0-28-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 23 23:03:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> cat /etc/lsb-release
>
> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
>
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
>
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
>
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10"

Comment: After the `apt-get update` have you done an `apt-get upgrade` a/o `apt-get dist-upgrade` to get your installed packages to their current versions? Also, the output you show suggests you are installing the i386 version, whereas your question states that you are looking for the 64-bit version.

Comment: well, I am looking for the version which gets installed and after that used. As I have a x86_64 GNU/Linux, i suppose that a 64bit version is applicable. I am not sure why apt-get wants to (also?) install the i386 version. But I trust that apt-get does the best for my intentions.

Comment: also I did not run any apt-get upgrade yet. I did excactly as stated above.

Comment: @zwets i did now run a `apt-get upgrade` but this changed nothing. In answer to you i386 question. I am not sure why this is the package chosen to install. But when looking in the listing of synaptic-manage the only 4.8 versions of gcc listed (and apparently installed) are of i386. The general gcc package though  is supposed to be 4.7. By "apparently installed" I mean that there is a green dot in fromt of that package. The shell output does not differ though.

Comment: So the problem that remains is *zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete* (held back broken packages). This is solved by a number of answers to the [Canonical Broken Packages Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). I will flag your question as a duplicate.

Comment: The reason you only see i386 packages instead of amd64 is that the amd64 build for GCC 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.10 is broken upstream:
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test/+packages