# Binary package for gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, gcc

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal), I have installed gcc 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 a couple of months ago.

Unfortunately, I encounter bugs very frequently, varying from failing to compile valid programs to crashing. With [one exception](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58435), I have been unable to reduce to a minimal sample and report the errors. I believe all are related to new C++11 features, mostly template aliases.

Now that [gcc 4.8.2 is out](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/), I would like to upgrade as soon as possible, but I would really prefer to do so with a binary package; my previous attempts to compile from source have failed. I have seen how to [compile from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836858/upgrade-gcc-4-6-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-to-4-8-2) specifically for Ubuntu 12.04 but I have not tried yet. I have also seen there's a [binary package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/gcc-4.8) for Ubuntu 14.04 but it does not appear to work on my 12.04, at least without removing my current installation of gcc 4.8.1.

So, is there any information whether a binary package of gcc 4.8.2 will be available for Ubuntu 12.04, and when?