# -std=c++11 not recognized on gcc 4.8.1

Tags: gcc

I just followed an answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal) question to update my gcc version to 4.8. 1 on Ubuntu 12.04, which I thought would support C++11. However it does not seem to.

When I try to compile something with `-std=c++11` flag, I get this error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’
```

My gcc version is this:

```
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)
```

My g++ version is this:

```
$ g++ -v
  ....
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

What could I be missing?

Edit: I was missing that I needed to update g++

It is easily achieved with a small modification to the code provided in the above mentioned answer. Just change `gcc` to `g++`.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50
```

Comment: Did you try with `g++`? What version of g++ do you have?

Comment: @muru The term _gcc_ has dual usage here. It is the name of the C compiler binary, but also stands for _GNU Compiler Collection_, of which both the gcc and g++ binaries are part of. The _cc1plus_ binary, is for c++ though.

Comment: @dobey Okay, so? O.o

Comment: The `gcc` and `g++` packages are separate. Upgrade `g++` as well. You have g++ v4.6 now, so c++-11 is not available.

Comment: You should compile with `-std=c++0x`. see updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have upgraded the C compiler, but not the C++ compiler. They are separate binary packages. You need to also install the `g++-4.8` package to get the new version of the C++ compiler.