# how to install downloaded g++4.8 deb archive in ubuntu 14.04 lts?

Tags: 14.04, deb, c++, g++

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The g++ compiler is missing in it. So, I downloaded g++ 4.8 deb archive. But I am not able to install it. ehn I open the package, ubuntu software center opens up and says dependency is not satisfiable:libstdc++-4.8-dev. please help.

Comment: The compiler is already in the repositories, just install `gcc` and `g++`.  You don't need to "download" it.

Answer (score 1):

The `g++` and `gcc` 4.8 compilers shoudl already be in 14.04

Try running this command: `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8 gcc-4.8` and see if it works.  It should then resolve the dependencies.

You may then have to update the alternatives.  Run this command afterwards to point everything to the 4.8.x compiler:  `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50`  <sub>(this information was obtained from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522387/std-c11-not-recognized-on-gcc-4-8-1))</sub>