# How do I install gcc 4.8 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, gcc, c, compiler

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04, and I need gcc 4.8 for MATLAB. So I tried to install gcc-4.8 using

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-117.118_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:3:1::f 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

so I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I didn't show any error but running gcc version command gave this

```
$ gcc -v
Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gcc
```

previously I used to have 7.5 but now it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install linux-libc-dev 
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt install gcc-4.8
```

Comment: could you tell how to remove current version of gcc because i read the comment given by SEKHR i installed latest version once again could you tell me how to remove current version 7.5.0 and use old version    

sudo apt-get --purge remove gcc  i tried by giving verion at end but it didnt work

Comment: There are two different ways to answer this comment 1. `sudo apt remove gcc-7` (which removes gcc 7.5 in 18.04) **2.** You can change the default gcc version by using the `update-alternatives` command to determine which actual file is referenced by a generic name, for example which actual file is referenced by `gcc`. For more information see the answers to this question: [How to change the default GCC compiler in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu).

Comment: it worked thank you

Answer (score 4):

In your terminal type: `sudo apt install gcc` and `enter`. That should install the latest version of `gcc`.

If you want to install GCC 4.8 specifically, you may follow the post: [How to install gcc-4.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8).

As GCC 4.8 is available in the default repository on Ubuntu 18.04, then you can simply do

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

Or
type `sudo apt-get install gcc-4` in terminal and press `tab`. If GCC 4.8 is available it will either auto-complete or show the available versions. If there are versions available other than 4.8 as well, add `.8` after `sudo apt-get install gcc-4` and press `enter` to install.

Answer (score 0):

Today, with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I can use gcc and gfortran version 4.11.2 with old fortran code. I don't think you should bother with gcc version 4.8.