# not able to install g++

Tags: g++

This is what I get when I run `sudo apt-get install g++`:

```
libgtksourceview-3.0-0 is already the newest version.
libgconf-2-4 is already the newest version.
ibus-gtk is already the newest version.
libqtgui4 is already the newest version.
libgssapi-krb5-2 is already the newest version.
ubuntu-extras-keyring is already the newest version.
libpam0g is already the newest version.
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
libgpg-error0 is already the newest version.
libdbusmenu-glib4 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-atspi-2.0 is already the newest version.
perl-modules is already the newest version.
lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure is already the newest version.
libcolorhug1 is already the newest version.
gedit-common is already the newest version.
libwebkitgtk-3.0-common is already the newest version.
system-config-printer-gnome is already the newest version.
libgcc-4.7-dev is already the newest version.
libtelepathy-logger3 is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-loma is already the newest version.
account-plugin-yahoo is already the newest version.
firefox-globalmenu is already the newest version.
libgpod4 is already the newest version.
libgail-3-0 is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-umpush is already the newest version.
xdg-user-dirs-gtk is already the newest version.
libgudev-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
libgtksourceview-3.0-common is already the newest version.
apport-gtk is already the newest version.
intel-gpu-tools is already the newest version.
libcanberra-gtk-module is already the newest version.
gnome-system-log is already the newest version.
account-plugin-jabber is already the newest version.
libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager is already the newest version.
libgweather-3-1 is already the newest version.
libdmapsharing-3.0-2 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-soup-2.4 is already the newest version.
language-selector-gnome is already the newest version.
account-plugin-google is already the newest version.
modemmanager is already the newest version.
python-gi is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-data is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is already the newest version.
xorg is already the newest version.
fonts-lklug-sinhala is already the newest version.
libtelepathy-glib0 is already the newest version.
libgrip0 is already the newest version.
libsignon-qt1 is already the newest version.
ubuntu-settings is already the newest version.
language-pack-gnome-en-base is already the newest version.
zeitgeist-core is already the newest version.
branding-ubuntu is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version.
apg is already the newest version.
thunderbird-globalmenu is already the newest version.
gnome-icon-theme-symbolic is already the newest version.
policykit-desktop-privileges is already the newest version.
sgml-base is already the newest version.
libdigest-hmac-perl is already the newest version.
unity-scope-gdrive is already the newest version.
libsignon-extension1 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 is already the newest version.
session-migration is already the newest version.
libunistring0 is already the newest version.
libdbus-glib-1-2 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-totem-1.0 is already the newest version.
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 is already the newest version.
manpages-dev is already the newest version.
telepathy-gabble is already the newest version.
grub-common is already the newest version.
account-plugin-twitter is already the newest version.
liblangtag-common is already the newest version.
libgc1c3 is already the newest version.
gedit is already the newest version.
libgrail6 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-core is already the newest version.
libgdata13 is already the newest version.
libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 is already the newest version.
glib-networking is already the newest version.
syslinux-legacy is already the newest version.
gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 is already the newest version.
libmagic1 is already the newest version.
libgcr-3-common is already the newest version.
signond is already the newest version.
libgoa-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome is already the newest version.
libpam-xdg-support is already the newest version.
ntfs-3g is already the newest version.
libpulse-mainloop-glib0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 is already the newest version.
libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 is already the newest version.
libelfg0 is already the newest version.
activity-log-manager-control-center is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-vmware is already the newest version.
gnome-contacts is already the newest version.
libavahi-glib1 is already the newest version.
python is already the newest version.
gir1.2-dee-1.0 is already the newest version.
rhythmbox-plugins is already the newest version.
gettext is already the newest version.
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-input-wacom is already the newest version.
libsemanage1 is already the newest version.
systemd-services is already the newest version.
grub-pc-bin is already the newest version.
ssh-askpass-gnome is already the newest version.
activity-log-manager-common is already the newest version.
libxxf86dga1 is already the newest version.
gnome-accessibility-themes is already the newest version.
libogg0 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-radeon is already the newest version.
geoclue is already the newest version.
libdpkg-perl is already the newest version.
libsgutils2-2 is already the newest version.
gvfs-backends is already the newest version.
libqt4-svg is already the newest version.
libgtop2-7 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-qxl is already the newest version.
gnome-control-center-data is already the newest version.
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-savage is already the newest version.
libapt-pkg4.12 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev is already the newest version.
software-center is already the newest version.
zeitgeist is already the newest version.
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-0 is already the newest version.
libpolkit-agent-1-0 is already the newest version.
libtag1-vanilla is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-input-evdev is already the newest version.
gconf2-common is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 is already the newest version.
remmina-plugin-vnc is already the newest version.
python3-gi is already the newest version.
python3-xdg is already the newest version.
gir1.2-atk-1.0 is already the newest version.
gnome-keyring is already the newest version.
libgnome-keyring-common is already the newest version.
libgettextpo0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 is already the newest version.
gcc-4.7 is already the newest version.
gnome-mines is already the newest version.
gir1.2-webkit-3.0 is already the newest version.
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets is already the newest version.
geoclue-ubuntu-geoip is already the newest version.
ubuntu-sso-client-qt is already the newest version.
zlib1g is already the newest version.
libcloog-ppl1 is already the newest version.
gnome-sudoku is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg is already the newest version.
libapt-pkg-perl is already the newest version.
libcanberra-gtk3-module is already the newest version.
gnome-font-viewer is already the newest version.
libglu1-mesa is already the newest version.
gsfonts is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-purisa is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-all is already the newest version.
update-manager-core is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-tools is already the newest version.
network-manager-pptp is already the newest version.
python3-update-manager is already the newest version.
manpages is already the newest version.
policykit-1-gnome is already the newest version.
libpython3.3-stdlib is already the newest version.
pppconfig is already the newest version.
libgcc1 is already the newest version.
gtk3-engines-unico is already the newest version.
gvfs-common is already the newest version.
bluez-gstreamer is already the newest version.
linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic is already the newest version.
libneon27-gnutls is already the newest version.
libgirepository-1.0-1 is already the newest version.
libreoffice-gnome is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 is already the newest version.
libgpgme11 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 is already the newest version.
gnome-session-canberra is already the newest version.
poppler-data is already the newest version.
system-config-printer-udev is already the newest version.
libasound2-plugins is already the newest version.
libcogl-common is already the newest version.
libcairo-gobject2 is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-x is already the newest version.
libmission-control-plugins0 is already the newest version.
libgtk-3-0 is already the newest version.
libcanberra-gtk3-0 is already the newest version.
libgdata-common is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-vesa is already the newest version.
ubuntu-wallpapers-raring is already the newest version.
lockfile-progs is already the newest version.
gnome-menus is already the newest version.
libglib-perl is already the newest version.
libegl1-mesa-drivers is already the newest version.
ubuntuone-control-panel-qt is already the newest version.
gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0 is already the newest version.
libjpeg-turbo8 is already the newest version.
logrotate is already the newest version.
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo is already the newest version.
gnome-session-common is already the newest version.
libpam-gnome-keyring is already the newest version.
ubuntuone-client-gnome is already the newest version.
gnome-control-center is already the newest version.
gsettings-desktop-schemas is already the newest version.
gnome-calculator is already the newest version.
gconf-service-backend is already the newest version.
libpango1.0-0 is already the newest version.
libjbig0 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-sisusb is already the newest version.
gir1.2-rb-3.0 is already the newest version.
genisoimage is already the newest version.
gnome-icon-theme is already the newest version.
libupower-glib1 is already the newest version.
libgeis1 is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-common is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-tdfx is already the newest version.
libxcb-glx0 is already the newest version.
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version.
python-gobject-2 is already the newest version.
guile-2.0-libs is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-kinnari is already the newest version.
dictionaries-common is already the newest version.
libgs9 is already the newest version.
gnome-session is already the newest version.
libgstreamer1.0-0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-pango-1.0 is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-typewriter is already the newest version.
telepathy-logger is already the newest version.
wget is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gdata-0.0 is already the newest version.
transmission-gtk is already the newest version.
libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 is already the newest version.
libgexiv2-2 is already the newest version.
libgnome-menu-3-0 is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-alsa is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-clutter is already the newest version.
libqt4-opengl is already the newest version.
librsvg2-2 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gudev-1.0 is already the newest version.
language-pack-en-base is already the newest version.
libnm-gtk-common is already the newest version.
gnome-orca is already the newest version.
libgtk2-perl is already the newest version.
gnome-bluetooth is already the newest version.
libpoppler-glib8 is already the newest version.
groff-base is already the newest version.
thunderbird-gnome-support is already the newest version.
gnupg is already the newest version.
gir1.2-ebook-1.2 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-cirrus is already the newest version.
account-plugin-flickr is already the newest version.
libaccounts-glib0 is already the newest version.
libgmime-2.6-0 is already the newest version.
libgail18 is already the newest version.
xul-ext-websites-integration is already the newest version.
account-plugin-windows-live is already the newest version.
wireless-regdb is already the newest version.
signon-plugin-password is already the newest version.
gir1.2-notify-0.7 is already the newest version.
libgutenprint2 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-r128 is already the newest version.
im-config is already the newest version.
xdg-utils is already the newest version.
unattended-upgrades is already the newest version.
libgusb2 is already the newest version.
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-typist is already the newest version.
libgs9-common is already the newest version.
grep is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-garuda is already the newest version.
gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 is already the newest version.
glib-networking-services is already the newest version.
libnl-genl-3-200 is already the newest version.
libavahi-gobject0 is already the newest version.
ghostscript-x is already the newest version.
python3-gdbm is already the newest version.
linux-image-generic is already the newest version.
libqt4-designer is already the newest version.
libxdamage1 is already the newest version.
keyboard-configuration is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-neomagic is already the newest version.
libmng1 is already the newest version.
printer-driver-gutenprint is already the newest version.
libgnomekbd-common is already the newest version.
gvfs-libs is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common is already the newest version.
libcogl-pango12 is already the newest version.
python-gnomekeyring is already the newest version.
geoip-database is already the newest version.
libjpeg8 is already the newest version.
librsvg2-common is already the newest version.
sessioninstaller is already the newest version.
libcompizconfig0 is already the newest version.
xdg-user-dirs is already the newest version.
libgstreamer0.10-0 is already the newest version.
gnome-disk-utility is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-modesetting is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 is already the newest version.
libsignon-plugins-common1 is already the newest version.
libslang2 is already the newest version.
unity-lens-shopping is already the newest version.
libgeoclue0 is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic is already the newest version.
libsemanage-common is already the newest version.
libgck-1-0 is already the newest version.
gucharmap is already the newest version.
liblightdm-gobject-1-0 is already the newest version.
libopenvg1-mesa is already the newest version.
libgweather-common is already the newest version.
libgail-common is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau is already the newest version.
xfonts-encodings is already the newest version.
libgtk-3-bin is already the newest version.
gnome-terminal-data is already the newest version.
libclutter-gst-2.0-0 is already the newest version.
libgxps2 is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-mono is already the newest version.
mcp-account-manager-uoa is already the newest version.
gconf-service is already the newest version.
grub-gfxpayload-lists is already the newest version.
gir1.2-accounts-1.0 is already the newest version.
libpangomm-1.4-1 is already the newest version.
python-gtk2 is already the newest version.
e2fsprogs is already the newest version.
python-gi-cairo is already the newest version.
libpaper1 is already the newest version.
python-gobject is already the newest version.
libsigc++-2.0-0c2a is already the newest version.
libnm-gtk0 is already the newest version.
gvfs is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-bin is already the newest version.
libglibmm-2.4-1c2a is already the newest version.
printer-driver-sag-gdi is already the newest version.
gnomine is already the newest version.
libgnutls26 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-mga is already the newest version.
libgpm2 is already the newest version.
python3-distupgrade is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-nice is already the newest version.
gzip is already the newest version.
dpkg is already the newest version.
grub-pc is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps is already the newest version.
thin-client-config-agent is already the newest version.
pkg-config is already the newest version.
overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 is already the newest version.
overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 is already the newest version.
gnome-mahjongg is already the newest version.
appmenu-gtk is already the newest version.
firefox-gnome-support is already the newest version.
liblocale-gettext-perl is already the newest version.
ubuntu-keyring is already the newest version.
libsignon-glib1 is already the newest version.
glib-networking-common is already the newest version.
libcanberra-gtk0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-freedesktop is already the newest version.
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins is already the newest version.
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio is already the newest version.
libcap-ng0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-wnck-3.0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-signon-1.0 is already the newest version.
libproxy1-plugin-gsettings is already the newest version.
totem-plugins is already the newest version.
gnome-user-share is already the newest version.
gir1.2-glib-2.0 is already the newest version.
gcr is already the newest version.
gcc is already the newest version.
ghostscript is already the newest version.
python-xdg is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-s3 is already the newest version.
dialog is already the newest version.
lightdm is already the newest version.
appmenu-gtk3 is already the newest version.
iputils-ping is already the newest version.
signon-keyring-extension is already the newest version.
python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-trident is already the newest version.
libgettextpo-dev is already the newest version.
libgssapi3-heimdal is already the newest version.
python-zeitgeist is already the newest version.
libwmf0.2-7-gtk is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version.
perl is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 is already the newest version.
libcogl12 is already the newest version.
indicator-messages is already the newest version.
libreoffice-ogltrans is already the newest version.
system-config-printer-common is already the newest version.
fonts-thai-tlwg is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-mach64 is already the newest version.
libnm-glib4 is already the newest version.
network-manager is already the newest version.
libcupscgi1 is already the newest version.
libgtkmm-3.0-1 is already the newest version.
libfftw3-single3 is already the newest version.
gnome-desktop3-data is already the newest version.
language-pack-gnome-en is already the newest version.
libzeitgeist-1.0-1 is already the newest version.
gnome-screensaver is already the newest version.
gir1.2-unity-5.0 is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-norasi is already the newest version.
libtag1c2a is already the newest version.
libjbig2dec0 is already the newest version.
gkbd-capplet is already the newest version.
libgphoto2-2 is already the newest version.
python3-pkg-resources is already the newest version.
gstreamer0.10-gconf is already the newest version.
python-imaging is already the newest version.
rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune is already the newest version.
gcc-4.7-base is already the newest version.
python-debtagshw is already the newest version.
libgnome-bluetooth11 is already the newest version.
gnome-control-center-unity is already the newest version.
libgupnp-1.0-4 is already the newest version.
gconf2 is already the newest version.
python3-gi-cairo is already the newest version.
fonts-takao-pgothic is already the newest version.
account-plugin-aim is already the newest version.
libgoa-1.0-common is already the newest version.
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base is already the newest version.
libgphoto2-l10n is already the newest version.
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 is already the newest version.
libdbusmenu-gtk4 is already the newest version.
libpackagekit-glib2-14 is already the newest version.
libgnome-keyring0 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-input-all is already the newest version.
network-manager-pptp-gnome is already the newest version.
fontconfig-config is already the newest version.
libwpg-0.2-2 is already the newest version.
libegl1-mesa is already the newest version.
signon-ui is already the newest version.
dconf-gsettings-backend is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 is already the newest version.
linux-generic is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-input-mouse is already the newest version.
remmina-plugin-rdp is already the newest version.
light-themes is already the newest version.
libfreerdp-plugins-standard is already the newest version.
libparse-debianchangelog-perl is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-bin is already the newest version.
firefox is already the newest version.
libreoffice-gtk is already the newest version.
fonts-tlwg-sawasdee is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
gnome-control-center-signon is already the newest version.
libpython2.7-stdlib is already the newest version.
libglewmx1.8 is already the newest version.
libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
libc6 is already the newest version.
language-selector-common is already the newest version.
ghostscript-cups is already the newest version.
gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 is already the newest version.
rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist is already the newest version.
gvfs-daemons is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 is already the newest version.
grub2-common is already the newest version.
zeitgeist-datahub is already the newest version.
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good is already the newest version.
libnm-glib-vpn1 is already the newest version.
libpng12-0 is already the newest version.
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gtk-3.0 is already the newest version.
compiz-gnome is already the newest version.
libgee2 is already the newest version.
account-plugin-salut is already the newest version.
libgmp10 is already the newest version.
lightdm-remote-session-freerdp is already the newest version.
gir1.2-vte-2.90 is already the newest version.
xdiagnose is already the newest version.
update-manager is already the newest version.
libgbm1 is already the newest version.
libisccfg90 is already the newest version.
rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder is already the newest version.
gstreamer0.10-x is already the newest version.
libgucharmap-2-90-7 is already the newest version.
rsyslog is already the newest version.
libglew1.8 is already the newest version.
powermgmt-base is already the newest version.
network-manager-gnome is already the newest version.
libvisual-0.4-plugins is already the newest version.
account-plugin-generic-oauth is already the newest version.
iputils-arping is already the newest version.
hardening-includes is already the newest version.
pulseaudio is already the newest version.
gvfs-fuse is already the newest version.
xorg-docs-core is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-ati is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion is already the newest version.
gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 is already the newest version.
libufe-xidgetter0 is already the newest version.
gstreamer0.10-alsa is already the newest version.
python-gconf is already the newest version.
gstreamer0.10-tools is already the newest version.
libgphoto2-port0 is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-peas-1.0 is already the newest version.
python-configglue is already the newest version.
libatk-bridge2.0-0 is already the newest version.
gnome-session-bin is already the newest version.
libgomp1 is already the newest version.
libmessaging-menu0 is already the newest version.
usb-creator-gtk is already the newest version.
libgnome-desktop-3-4 is already the newest version.
software-properties-gtk is already the newest version.
libcupsimage2 is already the newest version.
growisofs is already the newest version.
libio-string-perl is already the newest version.
gnome-power-manager is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How do I install g++ now?

Comment: Please, next time, don't use caps ;)

Comment: @rashik  run g++ -v and do inform what it returns

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem installing g++ ccompiler on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/514384/22949) (or if that doesn't work, see [Why can't I install g++?](http://askubuntu.com/q/175571/22949))

Answer (score 1):

It means that g++ is already installed!!

Linux comes with gcc already installed, so to compile your programs just use

```
g++ <filename>
```

If that doesnt work try

```
gcc <filename>
```

That should work.

Comment: It is not correct that g++ comes preinstalled. While the default image does include `gcc`, it does not include `g++`. See http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.manifest , for example. You first need to install `g++` (or a metapackage like `build-essential`).

Comment: ok..i thought that gcc also contained g++, because when i typed in my terminal g++ it seemed to work, and i have no knowledge of installing it..and when the question asker tries to apt-get install g++ it shows all the packages are already installed, so doesnt it mean that g++ is also installed? Or will he have to do apt-get install build-essesntial ?

Comment: looking at this post, gcc also seems to include g++  http://askubuntu.com/questions/248079/how-to-install-g-4-8?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You should always run that before installing or upgrading packages on the command-line (unless you've run it very recently). It fetches information about what packages are available in what versions from where.

You may simply be able to install `g++` now, 
Then try installing `g++` again:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```